# How to enable ssl without set commandName to IISEXPRES

Tags: c#, identityserver4, ids

In the Identity server empty template project I want to show logs in the command line.

Error:-

> In `launchSettings.json`
> when setup `"commandName": "Project"` command line run but ssl certificate invalid.
>
> [image]

When I do  `"commandName": "IISExpress"` SSL certificate is valid but  does not run via command line.

please help me with how to run logs in the command line and have SSL in Project mode simultaneously.

Answer (score 2):

To enable the SSL with in IIS Express, you have to just set “SSL Enabled = true” in the project properties window.

2- netsh http show sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:44300 //run this command as admin

Comment: in the IIS Express thats ok. my issue is using kestral. in this way ssl was not valid